# PyAutoGui and loops

Tags: python, pyautogui

I just want my whole code Below to be repeated to which value I set means if I set 10 so my code runs 10 times without asking any permission or input from me. The only way to stop is to wait or manually stop If anyone knows please solve my problem.. Full code to be repeated not some lines

from pyclick import HumanClicker
import pyautogui
import math
import time
import random
import os
import sys
from time import sleep
hc = HumanClicker()
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True

sleep(4)
coords = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('calc.png', confidence=0.6)

if coords is None:
print("image not found")

else:
hc.move((coords), 2)
hc.click()

coords1 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('calc1.png')
if coords1 is None:
print('Image not found on the screen!')

else:
hc.move((coords1), 2)
hc.click()

coords2 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('calc2.png')
if coords2 is None:
print('Image not found on the screen!')

else:
hc.move((coords2), 2)
hc.click()

coords3 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('calc4.png', confidence=0.6)
if coords3 is None:
print('Image not found on the screen!')

else:
hc.move((coords3), 0.5)
hc.click()

Comment: What type of loops are you thinking of? Is there a circumstance where you want to exit the loop?

Comment: please add more details what are you trying to achieve, "loop or something to my whole that keeps my code automatically running" has not much informative value

Comment: What parts do you want to repeat? When do you want the loop to stop? What issues did you run into when trying to implement loops? Do you think adding sleeps would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from pyclick import HumanClicker
import pyautogui
import math
import time
import random
import os
import sys
from time import sleep
hc = HumanClicker()
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True

sleep(4)

coords = []
NUMBER_OF_IMAGES = 4 # change this to your needs
for i in range(NUMBER_OF_IMAGES):
    coords[i] = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(
                                         ("calc" if i == 0 else "calc" + str(i))+".png",
                                         confidence = 0.6
                                        )
    if coords[i] is None:
        print("Image not found on the screen!")
    else:
        hc.move((coords[i]), 2)
        hc.click()
```

This just loops through all of the images, getting and (if coordinates are not `None`) clicking them.  All you have to do is set the number of images, `NUMBER_OF_IMAGES`.

Notes:

1. The `confidence` is `0.6`
2. The `math`, `time`, `random`, `os`, `sys`, and `time` modules are unnecessary.  To use `time.sleep`, use `pyautogui.sleep` (it was made so that you don't have to `import time`)
3. The `sleep(4)` statement does not seem helpful.

If this is part of a bigger project that requires those modules and `sleep(4)`, you should keep them.  Otherwise, try to remove unnecessary code from your Python program.

Comment: yes it is good code but it will just check these four images I want every pick to be chekced on different time interval so in my code I jusrt wanted it to be repeated up to value I set like if I set 10 it will start and run 10 times. The only way to stop was to stop manually or wait until it finishes running 10 times Hope you understand my question.

Comment: @MazharJr. : I'm sorry, but I don't understand.  Do you want to be able to choose the amount of images at runtime, or have a pause between each search of `calc*.png`, or be able to stop searching for `calc*.png` when the user wants to stop?  Can you please clarify your point?